# How to disable automatic report saving in SSRS 2013 report preview?

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL Server Reporting Services 2013 visual studio, is there any way to turn off the automatic report saving when previewing the report?

This was an option in 2008 and 2008 R2 and I can't find it so far in 2013.  I generally use the Preview to debug any formatting issues and the automatic saving is something I don't need.

Anybody know where/if this is possible?

Comment: SSRS is part of SQL Server, and we don't have a 2013 version of SQL Server - 2012 or 2014 - which one is it?

Comment: I believe @RickR is referring to Visual Studio 2013 with the Business Intelligence Toolset extension installed.

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to do that. When you preview the report it is automatically saved. (I get the feeling this has to do with it actually rendering from the file and not the un-saved data in Visual Studio.) If you have version control you could roll-back to the previous version if you've made changes you ended up not wanting.

Comment: Employer is requiring that we all move to the 2013 version since they just updated the server to 2013.  Thanks for the help!